# Not able to execute sudo command using subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, sudo, tee

I'm trying to change brightness by editing the brightness file in intel_backlight folder using Python Subprocess.

Cannot run the script with sudo priv.

Have tried mostly everything but still no luck...
Could you please help me a little as to where I'm going wrong.

Tried following:

1. With xbacklight package not working.
2. With xrandr colour getting dim but not brightness.
3. With changing the value of the file(work in shell with sudo but wanted through python with using sudo for calling python file).

#

```
command = "sudo  echo " + "'" + str(new_brightness_level) + "'" + ">" + "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-eDP-1/intel_backlight/brightness"
    subprocess.Popen(command,shell=True)
```

```
command2 = "echo {} | sudo -S   tee /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-eDP-1/intel_backlight/brightness ".format(new_brightness_level).split()

 c2 =subprocess.Popen(command2,shell=True,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,universal_newlines=True)
        res = c2.communicate(sudo_pass + '\n')[1]
```

#

```
command = "echo " + "'" + str(new_brightness_level) + "'" + "sudo -S > /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-eDP-1/intel_backlight/brightness"
cmd2 = subprocess.Popen(['sudo', '-S'] + command.split(),stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Thanks for the help in advance!!!

Comment: If you cannot run the script itself with `sudo`, how would you have `sudo` work from within it, to begin with?

Comment: @AKX Actually as per the requirement we can sudo from within the file. but cannot call whole file with sudo priv

Comment: "as per the requirement"... my question is how do you expect that to work? Would you expect your script to ask the user for their password then?

Comment: will be asking user for password in separate function then that function will call this function passing the sudo password

Comment: Okay, well – what happens when you try any of those methods? You're just saying they don't work.

Comment: For the second one which was the latest I tried (after passing the password in communicate) and using -S argument for sudo it still asked for password and within less than second moved ahead and gave error incorrect password attempt and script exited.(for the 2 was getting permission denied error as was not using tee as per what I read)

Comment: Are you trying to write a shell script in Python? Why not write it directly as a shell script instead?

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa it's part of a Python application that why needed to be integrated with Python as a function and called, Thanks! for your time though

Comment: @AKX Thanks for your time also!

Answer (score 0):

Was trying different things and finally found a workable solution to it :

```
command3 =  "echo {} | tee /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-eDP-1/intel_backlight/brightness ".format(new_brightness_level)
command4 =  " sudo -S  bash -c '{}' ".format(command3)
c1 =subprocess.Popen(command4,shell=True,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,universal_newlines=True)
res = c1.communicate(sudo_pass + '\n')[1]
```

In command 3 have created the command without Sudo

In command 4 first have added the sudo with -S(for getting password from 
communicate function) and have then used the bash shell which will be executed as sudo so all commands will be running using sudo

Kindly correct me and add further info if anyone feels
Much appreciated